# Laravel Group and Sum hasMany Relationship

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a `users` table with a column `country` and the user `belongsToMany` **Categories**. The user also `hasMany` relationship with a **Payments** table.

I am trying to:

1. Group the users by country showing the most popular category for each country (this is solved already)
2. Sum the `amount` columns in the `payments` table for each grouped country

Every time I try to join the `payments` table it returns multiple results which makes the sum entirely wrong. I believe I am not using the right query.

Here are the table structures:

**Users**

```
id | name  | country

1  | UserA | Canada
2  | UserB | USA
3  | UserC | Canada
```

**Categories**

```
id | Name
1  | Housing
2  | Cooking
```

**category_user**

```
id  | category_id | user_id
1   | 1           | 1
2   | 2           | 2
3   | 1           | 3
```

**Payments**

```
id | amount | user_id
1  | 500    | 1
2  | 200    | 2
3  | 150    | 1
4  | 100    | 3
```

The first problem has been solved using the code below:

```
return User::leftJoin('category_user as cu', 'users.id', '=', 'cu.user_id')
        ->join('categories as c', 'cu.category_id', '=', 'c.id')
        ->groupBy(['country', 'c.name'])
        ->get([
            'users.country',
            'c.name',
            DB::raw('count(*) as total')
        ])
        ->groupBy('country')
        ->values()
        ->map(function (Collection $elt) {
            return $elt->sortByDesc('total')->first();
        });
```

which results in something like this:

```
[
  {
    "country": "Canada",
    "name": "Housing",
    "total": 2
  },
  {
    "country": "USA",
    "name": "Cooking",
    "total": 1
  }
]
```

I would like to get the SUM(amount) from payments as total_payments. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: @Ersoy you input would be greatly appreciated 

Comment: Will `sum`s going to be category related ? is it going to be `sum of canada` or `sum of canada for housing` ?

Comment: Just for the country. Eg.: `sum of canada`

Comment: One more question, will `total` be `total number of payments` or `total number of users in the top category` ? Since a user can make multiple payments in the same/different categories it is not clear to what will be the total in that case ?

Comment: Ok, I need to see 1.) each country, 2.) total number of users in the country, 3.) most popular category for the country and 4.) total sum of payments for the country.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to minimize number of queries but following works on my local tests.

```
public function foobar()
{
    $popular = User::leftJoin('category_user as cu', 'users.id', '=', 'cu.user_id')
        ->join('categories as c', 'cu.category_id', '=', 'c.id')
        ->groupBy(['country', 'c.name'])
        ->get([
            'users.country',
            'c.name',
            DB::raw('count(*) as total')
        ])
        ->groupBy('country')
        ->values()
        ->map(function (Collection $elt) {
            return $elt->sortByDesc('total')->first();
        }); // this one is same (to get popular category)

    // this one for payments and number of users from that country
    return User::leftJoin('payments as p', 'users.id', '=', 'p.user_id')
        ->groupBy('country')
        ->get(['country', DB::raw('sum(p.amount) as total'), DB::raw('count(distinct(users.id)) as userCount')])
        ->map(function ($col) use ($popular) { // merging two collections into one
            $col->name = $popular->where('country', $col->country)->first()->name;

            return $col;
        });
}
```

It prints something like this;

```
[
  {
    "country": "Canada",
    "total": "1150",
    "userCount": 2,
    "name": "Housing"
  },
  {
    "country": "Italy",
    "total": "100",
    "userCount": 1,
    "name": "Kitchen"
  },
  {
    "country": "USA",
    "total": "200",
    "userCount": 1,
    "name": "Cooking"
  }
]
```

Comment: Thank you so much Ersoy! I really really appreciate your help.